# Запуск низкоуровневых программ

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, x86, bios

Пытаюсь разобраться с низкоуровневым программированием. Поставил задачу — написать "Hello World"-программу, записать её на флешку, перезагрузиться, запустить программу с флешки (*не запуская ОС*).

1. Можно ли это сделать на С или С++?
2. Как дать понять биосу, что её надо загрузить в память, выполнить?
3. Что из себя должна представлять программа? Исполняемый файл `.com`? `.bin` файл? Слышал, это должно быть 16-bit приложение.
4. Если ли какие-то ограничения в названии программы?
5. Немного не по теме: Стоит ли пользоваться MASM? Какой Ассемблер сейчас наиболее популярен для x86?

Заранне Спасибо!

Comment: Я совсем не знаток в этой области, но не думаю, что это возможно. Вопрос 2, в том-то и дело, что биосу сказать этого никак — он обращается при старте к загрузочному сектору, а не ко внешним устройствам. То есть, надо будет вручную при запуске вызывать программу. И, вероятно, из биоса можно только ОС грузить, а это слишком низкоуровнево, чтобы с лёгкой руки написать.

Comment: AivanF , Как это вручную? Так ведь загрузочный сектор и на флешке есть(или нет?)

Comment: Есть, но в меньшем приоритете. Сей равно надо как-то настроить биос будет.

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком обширный, пожалуйста, сократите его оставив только само важное.

Comment: AivanF , а, я понял о чём Вы говорите. Так это же не проблема вовсе)

Comment: AivanF , спасибо за ответ

Comment: Почитайте [эту статью](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-computers-boot-up/), а можно еще *до* и *после* (там ссылочки на другие статьи внизу).

Comment: да, можно. В качестве учебников рекомендую глянуть на rfc--net, masm-ru, да погуглить материалы Криса Касперски, например "дизассемблирование в уме" (не путайте с автором антивируса)

Answer (score 11):

Можно и на C/C++, но в очень урезанном виде - практически никаких библиотек. К вашим услугам только функции BIOS (`int 13h`) (Т.е. ваш "Hello, world" не должен выводиться ни с помощью `puts` или `printf`, ни тем более в `cout`). Никакой `main` в качестве входной точки (если только не измените соответствующим образом рантайм загрузчик). Т.е. только какие-то базовые вещи (типа арифметики :)), которые компилируются в `.obj`, и линкуются с начальным загрузчиком на ассемблере. Когда-то интереса ради урезал Turbo C++ до такого состояния - очень даже ничего получалось :)

Я в свое время использовал TASM - отлично подходил для таких целей.

Работать этот код начинает в реальном режиме, так что только 16 бит, причем (мы же о PC?) грузится он в память по адресу  `0000:7С00` и начинает выполняться оттуда. Грузится он из MBR, так что если это что-то более-менее большое - то сразу должен сам считать и загрузить остальное в память. Считайте, что com-файл DOS, только никаких `org 100h` - что получено, то просто положено в очень конкретную :) память - и на диске, и в RAM, и управление передается первому байту.

Соответственно, какое уж тут название программы... Название (файла) - это уже файловая система, а тут ею и не пахнет.

Мой совет: виртуальная машина с виртуальным дисководом для дискет :), грузящаяся с такой виртуальной дискеты. Первый сектор - ваш. Это позволит вам делать, что хотите, ничем не рискуя, и очень легко записывать ваше творение в файл, не мучаясь с записью в конкретные сектора на диске/флешке (при этом можно легко натворить неприятностей).

Answer (score 8):

1. Да.
2. Записать её в MBR флешки, а в BIOS выбрать загрузку с USB приоритетнее, чем с винчестера.
3. Проще всего получить ассемблерный листинг и ввести код с помощью HexEdit прямо в MBR диска.
4. Старайтесь в названии не использовать чужие торговые марки.
5. Стоит. Отличный ассемблер.

Comment: О HexEdit загуглю, разберусь. А как быть с Си\++?

Comment: @АртурКлочко Не нужен никакой HexEdit, проще програмку сделать что бы залиться в MBR или использовать готовые утилиты. Если из под linux, так вообще `dd if=file of=/dev/device bs=446 count=1` да, кстати код должен быть не более 446 байт, иначе не влезет и придется извращаться. Для hello world конечно за глаза хватит. Собирать com-файл, без org 100h (он же bin). Если вы компилятор C заставите собрать без библиотек и com файл то можно конечно и им

Comment: Mike , а как из под Винды записать? DMDE? Какой софт тогда нужен?

Comment: А чем сревато использование чужих товарных марок? Он ведь не собирается свой хелоуворлд продавать)

Comment: Ну, вдруг он захочет программу назвать Microsoft Hello.

Answer (score 3):

Если  хотите поизучать низкоуровневое программирование - начните с микроконтроллеров там все под это дело заточено. Рекомендую с avr начать - есть много хороших статей по asm и с - очень удобные среды разработки и эмуляторы. Это если Вам x86 не принципиален.

Comment: Да, знаю про микроконтроллеры, просто хочу сначала что-то более впечатляющее сделать. Спасибо!

Comment: http://easyelectronics.ru/category/avr-uchebnyj-kurs тут хорошие статьи на тему мк если надумаете. Там тоже  HW можно написать - как правило это вывод в uart строки.

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз подбираю материал для обучения.

Answer (score 1):

Да и практической пользы  изучив низкоуровневое программирование МК все же поболее будет. Мало чем отличаться будет программирование x86 или МК если писать на C (С++ не очень распространен среди мк) с точки зрения обучения.Если конечно   у Вас не стоит каких-то экзотических задач писать для 86 платформы.